# symbolic link command in Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, 12.04, server, lubuntu, symbolic-link

I wish to know about usage of Symbolic Link please. I saw it in "The Linux Command Line"
Fifth Internet Edition

Sincerely,
Davood

Comment: this is one of those questions where simply searching the internet for "symbolic link" would give you more than enough resources.

Comment: For future reference, it should be noted that 12.04 and 14.04 are EOL and therefore are off topic here.

Comment: Your question *tags* make no sense, you're asking about a Desktop (Lubuntu is a desktop system) but also not a Desktop but a Server?  Only supported releases of Ubuntu (*standard support*) are on-topic for this site (12.04 or the 2012-April release is EOL, 14.04 LTS is EOSS or ESM & off-topic here too). Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A symlink is a symbolic Linux/ UNIX link that points to another file or folder on your computer, or a connected file system. This is similar to a Windows shortcut. Symlinks can take two forms: Soft links are similar to shortcuts, and can point to another file or directory in any file system.